# Track the end of the WindowDragArea in flet

Tags: python, flet

How can I track the end of the Window Drag Area in `flet`

```
from flet import *


def main(page: Page):
    page.window_title_bar_hidden = True
    page.window_title_bar_buttons_hidden = True
    page.window_height = 200
    page.window_width = 300
    page.window_resizable = False
    page.window_center()

    def end_window_drag(e):
        pass

    page.add(
        Row(
            [
                WindowDragArea(
                    Container(
                        Text('Область перетаскивания'),
                        bgcolor=colors.AMBER_300,
                        padding=10),
                    expand=True,
                    maximizable=False
                ),
                IconButton(icons.CLOSE, on_click=lambda _: page.window_close())
            ]
        )
    )


app(main)
```